# Search Xml NodeList By Xpath and Bind In nested GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

i just want to bind xml in to gridview which multiple child node like this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Products>
<Product>
    <SKU>DL-DL4002</SKU>
    <Name>Leopard Print Strapless Corset Top with G-string</Name>
    <ImagePath4>
      http://da.com/images/product/large/DL-DL4002_4_.jpg
    </ImagePath4>
    <Variants>
      <Variant>
        <Size>S</Size>
        <Cost>25.28</Cost>
        <MSRP>57.45</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
      <Variant>
        <Size>M</Size>
        <Cost>25.28</Cost>
        <MSRP>57.45</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
      <Variant>
        <Size>L</Size>
        <Cost>25.28</Cost>
        <MSRP>57.45</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
      <Variant>
        <Size>XL</Size>
        <Cost>25.28</Cost>
        <MSRP>57.45</MSRP>
        <Avialability>out of stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
    </Variants>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <SKU>DL-DL4003</SKU>
    <Name>Designer Purple Brocade Party Corset Top</Name>

    <ImagePath4>
      http://da.com/images/product/large/DL-DL4003_4_.jpg
    </ImagePath4>
    <Variants>
      <Variant>
        <Size>S</Size>
        <Cost>23.1</Cost>
        <MSRP>52.5</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
      <Variant>
        <Size>M</Size>
        <Cost>23.1</Cost>
        <MSRP>52.5</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
      <Variant>
        <Size>L</Size>
        <Cost>23.1</Cost>
        <MSRP>52.5</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
      <Variant>
        <Size>XL</Size>
        <Cost>23.1</Cost>
        <MSRP>52.5</MSRP>
        <Avialability>in stock</Avialability>
        <Weight>0.6</Weight>

      </Variant>
    </Variants>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

,its ok when i bind this with gridview like that

```
 XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmldoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/XM.xml"));
  XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Products/Product");

     foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                     DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                    dtrow["SKU"] = node["SKU"].InnerText;
                }
```

its ok, but when i bind nested  gridview inside gridview For Varients on Row DataBound

like that,

```
protected void GridXML_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Products/Product/Variants/Variant");
        }
}
```

it will Select All variants Node For Both Object i.e Prodct SkU ID =DL-DL4000 and DL-DL4002   but i just Want  Select Only One object i.e one by one

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can use xpath predicate (`[]`) to filter elements for specific criteria. For example :

```cs
string sku = "DL-DL4002";
string xpath = String.Format("/Products/Product[SKU='{0}']/Variants/Variant", sku);
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.DocumentElement
                             .SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Above example will return `Variant` from `Product` having `SKU` equals `"DL-DL4002"`. I'm not familiar with ASP.NET gridview, but you should be able to get current `SKU` value from `e.Row` parameter.